# ASP.NET MVC Email Address Regular Expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, email

I am working on an application in MVC. However I am a bit stuck with the registration part of email address. What I would like to happen is that when a user signs up, they can only enter a specific type of email address and domain. I have a regular expression in my model that allows only specific domains and that works -

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+(@goldsmith\.ac\.uk)$", ErrorMessage = "Must enter your university email address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

So this would be allowed - `abcdef@goldsmith.ac.uk`, but this would not be - `abcdef@gmail.com`

However what I would the application to do is check the format the email address uses before the domain.

So this format is allowed - `ab1234c@goldsmith.ac.uk`, but anything other that this is not allowed. It must be two letters first, followed by 4 digit then finally another letter.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}(@gol....` (note you do not really need to add the `[EmailAddress]` attribute which is also performing another regex check)

Comment: Lovely! Thank you very much for that. I did not quite understand how the expressions work but now I got it. +1

Comment: @StephenMuecke You may answer if you wish.